# CSS float causes blank space

Tags: css, css-float

I have to show a list of divs in a seamless order, thought their heights may vary.
Here's an example:
[image: Example divs]

As you can see, when an element is floated to the left and is positioned next to another float it generates a white space until the next float. This doesn't happen the other way around. I can't seem to find a way around this and as I use javascript to filter out certain elements (divs) I can not create two different columns.

Here's the html/css:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: green;">
            <p>Float1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: blue;">
            <p>Float2</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
            <p>Float3</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: gray;">
            <p>Float4</p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: red;">
            <p>Float5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how to get it to look so that Float1 and Float3 don't have empty room between them?

Comment: What is it you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would consider changing the javascript instead of the css.

Comment: A List Apart has [an article on CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) `float`s this month. I advise reading it.

Comment: Based on Calum's example, I am trying to achieve something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/cELff/8/ As you see, with this example, the gap still appears when the Float1 is clicked. The only solution I can think of is creating two separated divs into which I place the elements, but I would prefer keeping the location data in each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example it might be possible using `float:left` for the uneven blocks and `float:right` for the even ones but in general this is not possible using just css. You will need javascript or 2 separate columns (or a combination...).

As you are using javascript already, it would be pretty easy to load all visible blocks in an array and divide them over two columns.

Comment: Using only float: left; and float: right; caused nearly the same effect under some conditions as explained in the question. So I separated my elements over two divs. To keep the number of elements in each div balanced, I iterate over all of them and even out the divs after a filter is applied/removed.

Comment: @Indrek That's how I did it once (assuming you are talking about javascript).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that toggling `float:left;` and `float:right;` does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cELff/1/

<strike>Try using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.</strike>

Comment: This only works if you know the size of all the boxes. If they're to be stacked like this dynamically, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I once used a jquery plugin which did it all, but I can't find it anywhere now.

Comment: Masonry seems really cool, but... The "expanded" part in my example is actually made visible with slideDown(). The way this would work with Masonry is by calling the .masonry() in the slideDown callback, but that hurts the effect a bit and for some reason throws all the items into one column. As I don't want to lose the effect, I guess I have to figure out reordering all the elements into two columns using left and right floating after I have filtered out some divs (as suggested by Calum and jeroen).

Answer (score 2):

appreciate this q is old, for others that find this in a search ( like I was searching ).

the reason for the space is the heights. try setting a height on the floated items.

Comment: It is not always possible to set a fixed height on all of your floated elements.

Comment: agree. Just, did not say in the question that that heights couldn't  be used.